# How to save emoji on text input as &#128584; or &#x1f648; instead of \ud83d\ude48

Tags: php, html, emoji, meta

I have a few forms that I need to be able to save emojis, and the emojis can be anywhere on a string.

I can't seem to get unicode sequences to display as emojis.

Currently, the forms call a javascript function that call a PHP page via ajax and there it's inserted in the database. I need to be able to insert it into the database as `\&#128584;` or `\&#x1f648;` instead of `\ud83d\ude48`.

The page meta is using charset=utf-8.
The relevant columns in the database are using Character set utf8mb4 and Collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

Comment: `\uXXXX` escapes are only valid in JSON, and `&#XXXX;` entities are only valid in HTML or XML documents. Decode it properly to UTF-8, store it properly as UTF-8, and re-encode _if necessary_ for a particular output method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. _“Currently, the forms call a javascript function that call a PHP page via ajax”_ - you should _show us_ what you are actually doing there, instead of giving us just a vague verbal description.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your php server needs to use this utility with the JSON response.

```php
$noEntities = html_entity_decode($JSON);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php